# CPU High in Chrome Task Manager

Tags: google-chrome

Hi all: I observed that one of Chrome tabs consume high CPU (40-50) in its built-in task manager. The windows task manager, however, only shows CPU 10 below for the same tab (same process id).

What is the CPU measurement that Chrome collect such that it has so large different than the windows task manager?

Regards,

Ricky